# docker image overwrite the user in base image

Tags: docker, jboss, dockerfile, wildfly, microservices

I have a child image(image X) which is derived from a parent image(say image Y, FROM Y:latest),
In parent image Y I have command as follow,

```
USER myuser

CMD ["myscript.sh"]
```

Here I expect that the script is executed by the user 'myuser'

In child image X, I am changing the user to,

```
USER myNewUser
```

when I build a container from this image X, I could see that 'myscript' is ran by 'myNewUser', not by 'myuser'

Any idea how to run a script in parent image using the user-defined in that image, please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

> when I build a container from this image X, I could see that
>   'myscript' is ran by 'myNewUser', not by 'myuser'

As per your this statement, your image is based on `X`, and you already overding user an image `X`.

```
USER myNewUser
```

So if you create image from `X` you will always get use `myNewUser`.

If you want the user of image `Y` just change the user in your any Dockerfile if the root image is Y just add

```
USER myuser
```

In short whatever user you will use that user will be used when your container up.

Comment: if i want to start some processes(by running some script defined in parent image Y) with 'myuser' and some other process with user 'myNewUser'(by running some script defined in parent image X)